# Finding $P (X\ge 1)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

If we have the distribution function

[image]

In part d they want us to find $P (X\ge1)$
So I found the probability distribution. Which is the sum of $f (t)$ for $t \ge 1$

But can we actually find it without the probability distribution and just from the distribution function ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: the distribution function , sometimes also called the probability function (of a RV) is just the probabilitiies the RV  attains this or that value(s). Thus, as you have $\;f_X(t)\;$ for (apparently) all the values the RV can attain, you are done.

Comment: The distribution function $F$ is related with the probability by $F(x) = P(X \leq x)$.

Comment: **Hint** : It is $P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X <1)$

Comment: **Hint** By definition, $F(x)=P(X\le x)$

Comment: Alternatively, it should be clear that $X$ has a discrete distribution (else $F$ wouldn't be a step function) taking on possible values $\{-1,1,3,5\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F(x)$ should be a cumulative distribution function, as noted in the comment.

You may rewrite $F(x)$ as probability mass function $$P(x)=\left\{\begin{array}  \\ 0.25\text{ for } x=-1,1,3 \text{ or } 5 \\ 0 \text{ otherwise} \end{array} \right. $$

Hence $P(X\geq1)=P(X=1)+P(X=3)+P(X=5)=0.75$.